# Android cursorAdaper in list view with onitemclick

Tags: android

can you help me, i have such DB:

```
public static final String DB_CREATE =
            "create table " + DB_TABLE + " (" +
                    COLUMN_ID + " integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    COLUMN_PATH + " text UNIQUE," +
                    COLUMN_NAME + " text," +
                    ");";
```

In another class

```
final Cursor cursor = activity.getDb().getEByPath(path);
        String [] colums = new String[]{
            DB.COLUMN_NAME
        };
        int[] to = new int[]{
                R.id.text
        };
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.file_list_item,
                cursor,
                colums,
                to,
                0);
        final ListView filesTable = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.files_list);
filesTable.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long id) {
                Cursor cursor1 = (Cursor)cursorAdapter.getItem(pos);
                Log.d(TAG, cursor1.getString(cursor1.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DB.COLUMN_PATH)));
            }
        });

        filesTable.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
```

So after click on my item i want to get some more info, which store in database. But i can't get smth else except my `COLUMN_NAME` what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you handle give with the columns Array the `Cursor` only reads the Name Column from the Database and not the other columns. You will have to either load all data directly into one `Cursor` and then use a custom Adapter to set the data to the TextView. Or you can run a new query in `onItemClick()` and get the additional information from the new `Cursor`.

Answer (score 0):

You are only giving your adapter the COLUMN_NAME... If you want to show more, 
add more fields:

```
  String [] colums = new String[]{
        DB.COLUMN_NAME
        DB.ANOTHER_NAME
        DB.ONE_MORE_NAME
    };
```

Your adapter only wants to populate a single field, but you can use the extra data to for a popup or dialog with the extra information in the Strings